# how many predecessors of entered number are prime numbers?

Tags: c

/* Write a program in the C programming language in which two natural numbers, K and T, are entered from the keyboard, the K must be one-digit number and the T must be two-digit number. For each entered two-digit number T display on the screen
information on whether there are K of its predecessors which are prime numbers. The sequence of entering numbers
interrupt by entering any value that does not meet the specified conditions. In case of  not entering any correct pair of numbers, write the corresponding message on the screen. */

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int k,t,s=0,i,j,count;
    do
    {
        printf("\nenter one one-digit and one two-digit number.\n");
        scanf("%d%d",&k,&t);
        s++;

        count=0;

        for(i=1; i<=t; i++)
        {
            for(j=2; j<=t/2; j++)
            {
                if(j%i==0)
                count++;
            }
        }

        if(count==k)
        printf("\nentered number %d has %d predecessors which are prime numbers.",t,k);

        else
        printf("\nentered number %d does not have %d predecessors which are prime numbers.",t,k);

    }
    while(k<10 && k>0 && t>9 && t<100);

    if(s==1)
    printf("\nuncorrect pair was entered.");

}
```

I tried solving it in this way, but code does not work and I do not know why

expected output eg. k=8 and t=21 
entered number 21 has 8 predecessors which are prime numbers.

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). **StackOverflow is *not* a *do-my-homework* website.** See also this [C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Comment: And learn to use a debugger such as [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/); see also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight

Answer (score 1):

Replaced your `for`

```
for (i = 2; i <= t; i++) {
        int isPrime = 1;
        for (j = 2; j < t; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0 && i != j) {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime)
            count++;
    }
```